# Change Bundle ID in AppStoreConnect/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I'm trying to upload an app to the Apple store and I can't get the Bundle ID to match on Xcode and in AppStore Connect (ASC). In ASC there is an id with spaces in it and in Xcode there is a different id with no spaces. I can't change the ASC one even though I haven't uploaded the bundle yet. So I tried changing it in Xcode and I can change that one, but in Xcode spaces get automatically replaced with dashes, so it's impossible for me to make the two match. Is there any way around this short of deleting everything and starting the whole process over?

I am using Xcode version 12.5 and whatever version of ASC is current on their website in May 2021.

Comment: I wonder how you created an bundle id with spaces in ASC. If I try so, I'll get an error and cannot proceed.

Comment: I also don't know how I was able to do that. My solution ended up just creating a new app and starting from scratch. So frustrating.